# JPA non-entity with select database result to List<object[]>

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a REST API for Android using my yii2 fremowork blocking site and its database.
I did not need to create a table in the database, but I would only SELECT and INSERT the information in the desired style.
How can I do this in the Java Spring boot application?
I need to download the information you need

This is my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/uzaart_teda?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

My Service implement class

```
@Service
public class ProductsServiceimpl implements ProductsService{
    @Autowired
    ProductsRepository productsRepository;
    @Override
    public List<ProductsDto> getProducts() {
        List<ProductsDto> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new ProductsDto(1,2,"anvar",4,5,6,7));
        list.add(new ProductsDto(1,2,"sanjar",4,5,6,7));
        /*this is my need --->*/
        List<Object[]> objects=productsRepository.selectProducts();
        /******/
        System.out.println(objects.size());
        return list;
    }
}
```

This is my Repository

```
public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Object[],Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT a.id,a.tovar_id,t.nom_sh,a.kol_ost,a.kol_in_ost, a.opt1 AS sot,a.opt1_in AS sot_in FROM s_tovar t,asos_slave a,asos WHERE   a.del_flag=1 AND (asos.tur_oper=1 OR asos.tur_oper=4 OR asos.tur_oper=5) AND a.asos_id=asos.id AND a.tovar_id=t.id AND (a.kol_ost>0 OR a.kol_in_ost>0) AND asos.client_id = 4 AND (((t.nom LIKE \"%0001%\") OR (t.nom LIKE \"%0001%\"))) ORDER BY t.nom,a.srok",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object[]> selectProducts();

}
```

My result.
Error message 
1.
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2019-07-16 16:20:19.006 ERROR 7328 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productsService';
```

2.

```
[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

3.

```
at com.uz.shopapi.ShopApiApplication.main(ShopApiApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productsServiceimpl':
```

Comment: Please update your question with full `stacktrace`. Also add `service` & `controller` sources too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

`public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Object[],Long> {`

JpaRepository must be of type of class that is annotated with `@Entity:`

`public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {`

like this:

```
@Entity
class Product {
  …
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.multiple-modules.annotations

Answer (score 0):

You have to create entities to use Spring Data JPA, because it needs the entity metadata to create query.
After that, you can use custom object to select result into it.

```
public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Products,Long> {
    @Query(select new com.xyt.CustomObject(a.tovar_id,t.nom_sh ... ) from ENTITY1 a, ENTITIY2 t where ...)
    public List<CustomObject> selectProducts();

}
```

Alternatively, you can use simple JDBC template to create sql query with your custom object mapper. In this way you do not need to create those entities.